# adding total function to multiple rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 fields named item, price, quantity and total. All I want to do is calculate total(price * quantity) for each row and a grand total adding the 'total' field in all the rows.

My script is,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".price").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    $("#sum").html('&pound;' + sum.toFixed(2));
}
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('.del').live('click',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
    $('.add').live('click',function(){
        $(this).val('Delete');
        $(this).attr('class','del');
        var appendTxt = "<tr><td><input name='item[]' type='text' size='40' /></td><td><input name='qty[]' type='text' size='5' value='0' /></td><td><input class='price' name='price[]' id='price' type='text' size='20' value='0.00' /></td><td><input name='total[]' class='total' id ='total' type = 'text' size='50' value='0'></td><td><input type='button' class='add' value='Add Row' /></td></tr>";
        $("tr:last").after(appendTxt);  
    });
    $('.price').live('keyup', function() {
        calculateSum();
    });         
});
</script>
```

and my HTML is,

```
<table id="options-table">                   
        <tr>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Qty</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>                  
        <tr>
            <td><input name="item[]" type="text" size="40" /></td>
            <td><input name="qty[]" type="text" value="0" size="5" /></td>
            <td><input name="price[]" class="price" id="price" type="text" value="0.00" size="20" /></td>
            <td><input name="total[]" class="total" id ="total" type = "text" size="50"></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" /></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="sum">&pound;0.00</div>
```

What iam getting is only the sum of all price fields. How to apply sum function for each row and grand total. Please someone help me to achieve this.

Comment: Sorry iam not aware of that, could you pls explain me ??

Comment: sure have a look at this very basic sample http://jsbin.com/ITOMixE/3/edit ( suggest you to learn it. it's the hootest thing right now and I think it's gonna be here for a long time)

Comment: @RoyiNamir, Angular is a huge undertaking, particularly for someone who is most probably a JS beginner. I don't think it's a great suggestion. And I'd question your statement that it's the hottest thing right now, too.

Comment: @Andy As I wasnt putting any answer ,I just said it as a comment. ( 4 lines with ng). And I do think that ng is the hotest thing now days. (imo). and I dont think im wrong

Comment: Is only my opinion but not learn angular before you have a strong knowledge of **JAVASCRIPT** ...

Answer (score 0):

I hope to have understand... calculate the total of each row (also the new ones if added).

#### you need some refactoring on HTML:

1. Not use unique ID (because you need to add more form like you shown) - `id="price"` `id="total"` remove them.
2. Add class `qty` on field named `qty[]` (i prefer for find the element)

#### ow add a new function for calculate the total in each row:

```
  function calculateTotal(){
    $("#options-table tr").not(":eq(0)").each(function(){ //.not(":eq(0)") first is header of table
        var pr = parseInt($(this).find(".price").val());
        var q = parseInt($(this).find(".qty").val());
        $(this).find(".total").val(pr*q); 
    });
  }
```

every time you call this function js calculate the total of **all** row.

this for calculete **only one**:

```
  function calculateRowTotal($row){ // $row must be one of your $("tr")
        var pr = parseInt($row.find(".price").val());
        var q = parseInt($row.find(".qty").val());
        $row.find(".total").val(pr*q); 
  }
```

all code, with some edits:

### HTML:

```
<table id="options-table">                   
    <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>Qty</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>                  
    <tr>
        <td><input name="item[]" type="text" size="40" /></td>
        <td><input name="qty[]" class="qty" type="text" value="0" size="5" /></td>
        <td><input name="price[]" class="price" type="text" value="0.00" size="20" /></td>
        <td><input name="total[]" class="total" type = "text" size="50"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br /><br />
<div id="sum">&pound;0.00</div>
```

### JS:

```
function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".total").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    $("#sum").html('&pound;' + sum.toFixed(2));
}
function calculateTotal(){
    $("#options-table tr").not(":eq(0)").each(function(){ //.not(":eq(0)") first is header of table
        var t = parseInt($(this).find(".price").val()) * parseInt($(this).find(".qty").val());
        if(isNaN(t)) return alert("insert only number inside of fileds, please");
        $(this).find(".total").val(t); 
    });
  }
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('.del').live('click',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
    $('.add').live('click',function(){
        $(this).val('Delete');
        $(this).attr('class','del');
        var appendTxt = "<tr><td><input name='item[]' type='text' size='40' /></td><td><input name='qty[]' type='text' size='5' value='0' /></td><td><input class='price' name='price[]' id='price' type='text' size='20' value='0.00' /></td><td><input name='total[]' class='total' id ='total' type = 'text' size='50' value='0'></td><td><input type='button' class='add' value='Add Row' /></td></tr>";
        $("tr:last").after(appendTxt);  
    });
    $('.price, .qty').on('change', function() {
        calculateTotal();
        calculateSum();
    });         
});
```

Comment: I have tried your code, it is working correctly for the first row only! If i add a second row, its not calculating the total.

Answer (score 0):

I made my script to give a unique id to each field

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function calculateSum() {
        var sum = 0;
        $(".price").each(function() {
            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });
        $("#sum").html('&pound;' + sum.toFixed(2));
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        $('.del').live('click',function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
        $('.add').live('click',function(){
            $(this).val('Delete');
            $(this).attr('class','del');
            var appendTxt = "<tr><td><input name='item[]' type='text' size='40' /></td><td><input name='qty[]' type='text' size='5' value='0' /></td><td><input class='price' name='price[]' id='price' type='text' size='20' value='0.00' /></td><td><input name='total[]' class='total' id ='total' type = 'text' size='50' value='0'></td><td><input type='button' class='add' value='Add Row' /></td></tr>";
            $("tr:last").after(appendTxt);  
        });
        $('.price').live('keyup', function() {
            calculateSum();
        });         
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

is working !!  add jquery 1.9.1 library file to the above code.

Comment: nice. but remove useless (and duplicate) ID like `id='price'`.